# I'm trying to check all child check boxes when parent is checked. But this works only once ! When i try it the next time, child doesn't gets checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.links > input').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().children('.subLinks').children('.subLinkCheck').children().attr('checked', true);
        } else 
          $(this).parent().children('.subLinks').children('.subLinkCheck').children().attr('checked', false);;
    });
});
```

It works fine the first time. When I uncheck the child checkbox and then click on the parent checkbox, it fails,

This is the  HTML content

```
<ul id="mainLink">
    <li class="links">
        <input type="checkbox" />Interactive Community
        <ul class="subLinks">
            <li class="subLinkCheck">
                <input class="1" type="checkbox" />Usability Testing</li>
            <li class="subLinkCheck">
                <input type="checkbox" />HFI Certification</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="links">
        <input type="checkbox" />Heuristic Evaluations
        <ul class="subLinks">
            <li class="subLinkCheck">
                <input type="checkbox" />Usability Testing</li>
            <li class="subLinkCheck">
                <input type="checkbox" />HFI Certification</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd need so much space to the left of the HTML code. Proper formatting increases readability!

Comment: Sorry, Thanks for formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jrrnj/

Comment: .prop('checked', true); and .prop('checked', false)